# Get table name of an entity for a query in TYPO3 Flow

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, typo3-flow

Does anybody know how to get the table name of an entity within a repository class? With Extbase this seems to be easily possible but I can't find no helper class within TYPO3 Flow. I need this for a raw SQL query within the repository of an entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM: http://wiki.typo3.org/Flow_Cookbook#Execute_arbitrary_DQL. So with the DQL I'm able to use the class names directly in a query.

```
/**
 * @Flow\Inject
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
 */
protected $entityManager;

[...]

$dql = 'SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Vendor\Package\Domain\Model\Entity e WHERE e.property = :property';

$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($dql);
$query->setParameters(array('property' => $property));
$result = $query->execute();
```